# Substring pattern matching in two files

Tags: perl, grep, pattern-matching

I have an input flat file like this with many rows:

```
Apr  3 13:30:02 aag8-ca-acs01-en2 CisACS_01_PassedAuth p1n5ut5s 1 0 Message-Type=Authen OK,User-Name=joe7@it.test.com,NAS-  IP-Address=4.196.63.55,Caller-ID=az-4d-31-89-92-90,EAP Type=17,EAP Type Name=LEAP,Response Time=0,
Apr  3 13:30:02 aag8-ca-acs01-en2 CisACS_01_PassedAuth p1n6ut5s 1 0 Message-Type=Authen OK,User-Name=bobe@jg.test.com,NAS-IP-Address=4.197.43.55,Caller-ID=az-4d-4q-x8-92-80,EAP Type=17,EAP Type Name=LEAP,Response Time=0,
Apr  3 13:30:02 abg8-ca-acs01-en2 CisACS_01_PassedAuth p1n4ut5s 1 0 Message-Type=Authen OK,User-Name=jerry777@it.test.com,NAS-IP-Address=7.196.63.55,Caller-ID=az-4d-n6-4e-y2-90,EAP Type=17,EAP Type Name=LEAP,Response Time=0,
Apr  3 13:30:02 aca8-ca-acs01-en2 CisACS_01_PassedAuth p1n4ut5s 1 0 Message-Type=Authen OK,User-Name=frc777o.@it.test.com,NAS-IP-Address=4.196.263.55,Caller-ID=a4-4e-31-99-92-90,EAP Type=17,EAP Type Name=LEAP,Response Time=0,
Apr  3 13:30:02 aag8-ca-acs01-en2 CisACS_01_PassedAuth p1n4ut5s 1 0 Message-Type=Authen OK,User-Name=frc77@xed.test.com,NAS-IP-Address=4.136.163.55,Caller-ID=az-4d-4w-b5-s2-90,EAP Type=17,EAP Type Name=LEAP,Response Time=0,
```

I'm trying to `grep` the email addresses from input file to see if they already exist in the master file.

Master flat file looks like this:

```
a44e31999290;frc777o.@it.test.com;20150403
az4d4qx89280;bobe@jg.test.com;20150403
0dbgd0fed04t;rrfuf@us.test.com;20150403
28cbe9191d53;rttuu4en@us.test.com;20150403
az4d4wb5s290;frc77@xed.test.com;20150403
d89695174805;ccis6n@cn.test.com;20150403
```

If the email doesn't exist in master I want a simple count.

So using the examples I hope to see: `count=3`, because `bobe@jg.test.com` and `frc77@xed.test.com` already exist in master but the others don't.

I tried various combinations of grep, example below from last tests but it is not working.. I'm using grep within a perl script to first capture emails and then count them but all I really need is the count of emails from input file that don't exist in master.

```
grep -o -P '(?<=User-Name=\).*(?=,NAS-IP-)' $infile $mstr > $new_emails;
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use this approach in `awk`:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {FS=";"; a[$2]; next}
       {FS="[,=]"; if ($4 in a) c++}
       END{print c}' master file
3
```

This works by setting different field separators and storing / matching the emails. Then, printing the final sum.

For `master` file we use `;` and get the 2nd field:

```
$ awk -F";" '{print $2}' master 
frc777o.@it.test.com
bobe@jg.test.com
rrfuf@us.test.com
rttuu4en@us.test.com
frc77@xed.test.com
ccis6n@cn.test.com
```

For `file` file (the one with all the info) we use either `,` or `=` and get the 4th field:

```
$ awk -F[,=] '{print $4}' file
joe7@it.test.com
bobe@jg.test.com
jerry777@it.test.com
frc777o.@it.test.com
frc77@xed.test.com
```

Comment: Ah, that works! Thank you very much and for explaining details fedorqui, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Think the below does what you want as a one liner with diff and perl:

```
diff <( perl -F';' -anE 'say @F[1]' master | sort -u ) <( perl -pe 'm/User-Name=([^,]+),/; $_ = "$1\n"' data | sort -u ) | grep '^>' | perl -pe 's/> //;'
```

The `diff <( command_a |sort -u ) <( command_b |sort -u) | grep '>'` lets you handle the set difference of the command output.

`perl -F';' -anE 'say @F[1]'` just splits each line of the file on ';' and prints the second field on its own line.

`perl -pe 'm/User-Name=([^,]+),/; $_ = "$1\n"'` gets the specific field you wanted ignoring the surrounding key= and prints on a new line implicitly.

Comment: `| wc -l` if all you need is the count ;P

Comment: Thanks Matt, that works very nicely from cmd line also, trying to figure out how to merge it into the existing perl script to get it to work.

Comment: I have it like this but it's throwing an error. 
`diff <( perl -F';' -anE 'say @F[1]' $mstr | sort -u ) <( perl -pe 'm/User-Name=([^,]+),/; $_ = "$1\n"' $infile | sort -u ) | grep '^>' | perl -pe 's/> //;' | wc -l > $outcount`;

sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `diff <( perl -F';' -anE 'say ' macid-master.csv | sort -u ) <( perl -pe 'm/User-Name=([^,]+),/;  = "'

Comment: That most certainly isnt exactly what you have in your perl script... The $_ and $1 looks like its being interpreted before it gets to the shell so my guess is you have the whole thing in back ticks in you perl script? If you already have a perl script why not just do all of this properly in there with a couple of hashes?

Comment: Yes, I added back ticks, I'll try it with a couple hashes.. Thanks again Matt.

Comment: To get it working as is use system() and juggle the quote usage.